# What is correct way to create .bar file in Blackberry 10 native SDK?

Tags: blackberry-10

I am using Momentics IDE for building apps for my BB10 device.

I have created one app and renamed it, but during installing bar file(Which is exist in BAR packages folder) in my BB10 device it stuck in this screen.

[image: Installing bar file]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add debug token in bar-description file
2. Run project as device debug
3. Connect your device using USB/WIFI
4. Now run your project. It will install .bar file in your device

Comment: yes...it works but only taking some more time to install on device. I think it is because of native app.

Comment: while install it takes some time depend upon your app size or types of libraries used.